# Inserting simply SUM in a cell formula results in Run-time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

While trying to set some data from one spreadsheet to another in the same excel file it gives a Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error. By debugging the code stops to work below when I'm trying to assign to that cell s.

```
Worksheets("Lista Sc").Select
    With Sheets("Lista Sc")
    
    .Range(Cells(riga, 3), Cells(riga + n, 3)).MergeCells = True
    .Range(Cells(riga, 5), Cells(riga + n, 5)).MergeCells = True
    .Range(Cells(riga, 21), Cells(riga + n, 21)).MergeCells = True
    s = "=SOMMA(S" + CStr(riga) + ";T" + CStr(riga + 1) + ":T" + CStr(riga + n) + ")-L" + CStr(riga)
    .Cells(riga, 21).FormulaLocal = s
```

It's the first time I'm trying to face problems with excel macro, so I have no idea on what's going on.

Comment: The formula looks ok to me, assuming that is how you would enter it yourself. If you enter the formula manually into a cell and then use `?activecell.formulalocal` in the immediate window, what is the output?

Comment: @Rory I'm sorry, can you explain me how to perform your suggestion?

Comment: I mean enter something like `=SOMMA(S2;T3:T50)-L2` into a cell in column U on the Lista Sc sheet, then with that cell selected, enter the code I posted into the immediate window and press Enter, and see what the output is.

Comment: Wouldn't it still be `=SUM()` even if language of their excel is Spanish/Italian, not `=SOMMA()` @Rory ?

Comment: @Rory it seems to be that   =SOMMA(S2;T3:T50)-L2   has a structure that is not correct indeed when I switch to Visual Basic the immediate windows is freezed and Excel pop up a windows by saying I cannot write formulas like this.

Comment: @Notus_Panda by changing SOMMA into SUM the error comes anyway

Comment: And how do you normally write your SUM/SOMMA in excel? Make a SUM like you normally would with excel and try Rory's formula again in the immediate window.

Comment: @Rory It was a problem of language, by switching in italian the test works. So when putting that test SUM formula in random cell and then go to the immediate window the output is the correct sum. So?

Comment: I suggest you use English then with the Formula property: `.Cells(riga, 21).Formula = "=SUM(S" + CStr(riga) + ",T" + CStr(riga + 1) + ":T" + CStr(riga + n) + ")-L" + CStr(riga)`

Comment: @Notus_Panda not with the `FormulaLocal` property, no. That uses whatever the user's Excel is set to (which is one reason it's not used as often).

Comment: @Rory can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct 'cause It works!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use English with the Formula property, which will work regardless of the user's language settings:

```
.Cells(riga, 21).Formula = "=SUM(S" + CStr(riga) + ",T" + CStr(riga + 1) + ":T" + CStr(riga + n) + ")-L" + CStr(riga)
```